# Java send ByteArray as a param to a method which expects MultipartFile

Tags: java, spring

Lets say I have a method `sendFile(MultipartFile file)` and I want to send a `ByteArray file` as a param

```
ByteArray file = ...
ByteArrayResource bar = new ByteArrayResource(file)
sendFile(bar)
```

I have converted the **ByteArray** to **ByteArrayResource** and sending it to the method expecting MultipartFile, but I get a compilation error:

**Type mismatch. Required: MultipartFile, Found: ByteArrayResource**

Why am I getting this error?

This is the hierarchy of the MultipartFile interface:

```
MultipartFile -> InputStreamSource -> ByteArrayResource
```

Comment: Well - ByteArrayResource does not implement MultipartFile. Both are InputStreamSource, but that they are not related otherwise, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

First, if your method takes a `MultipartFile`, you must send it a `MultipartFile` or another class that IS a `MultipartFile`.  A `ByteArrayResource` IS NOT a `MultipartFile`, but a `MultipartFile` HAS a `ByteArrayResource`.  Read up on the distinction between HAS-A vs. IS-A.

Also, since presumably you wrote the sendFile method, why not overload it and create a version that takes a ByteArrayResource?

If you must use a `MultipartFile`, you'll need to create one to send to this method.

```
MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("arbitrayFileName", bas.getByteArray());
```

Comment: I wouldn't like to use mock classes in production code

Comment: The signature of the method comes from a dependency library

Comment: MockMultipartFile is not a mock, despite its name.  If you have to use a MultipartFile, you have to either use one of the implementations that Spring provides (CommonsMultipartFile, MockMultipartFile) or write your own implementation.  There's not much else you can do; if the method takes a MultipartFile, you must send it a MultipartFIle.